# Set of Convergence for This Series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

What is the set of convergence for this series: $$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \bigg(\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\bigg)^3\bigg(\dfrac{3z-1}{2}\bigg)^n $$  My initial thought is to use, $ \dfrac{1}{R} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\Big(\bigg\vert\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg\vert\Big)$. I am stuck simplifying after I plug in the $n$th and $(n+1)$th terms.

Comment: By $2n!!$, do you mean $(2n)!!$ or $2(n!!)$?

Comment: I have corrected it, sorry @TheSubstitute

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Amplify the whole fraction by $(2n)!!=2^n~n!$ and then use the asymptotics of the [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient), which are ultimately based on [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation). As an aside, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigg\{4^{-n}~{2n\choose n}\bigg\}^3~x^n~=~\bigg\{\frac2\pi~K\bigg(\sqrt{\tfrac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}2}\bigg)\bigg\}^2,$$ which should give you a pretty good idea about the values of $x=\dfrac{3z-1}2$ for which the series converges.

Comment: See [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) for more information.